# HTML5 Cache Manifest Cache Everything

Tags: html, caching, manifest

Is there a way to "cache everything" on a website so that you dont have to add every resource by uri to the manifest?

Something like:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
*.png
```

instead of

```
CACHE MANIFEST
my_image_1.png
my_image_2.png
my_image_3.png
my_image_4.png
my_image_5.png
my_image_6.png
my_image_7.png
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I specify a wildcard in the HTML5 cache manifest to load all images in a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001196/how-do-i-specify-a-wildcard-in-the-html5-cache-manifest-to-load-all-images-in-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No: the CACHE section doesn't allow wildcards. But if it's simpler for you insert the manifest entry () in every page you want to cache. Every page with that entry gets cached even without being included in the manifest (master entries).