# Caching all resources of the html page with HTML5 app cache

Tags: html, caching, web, manifest, offline

Is there a way to specify (in the cache manifest file) that all the resources included in the html page are to be cached?

I'm building a dynamic web app and want to give the user the ability to view the app while offline. Therefore I need all the images (for which the source is set from file names stored in the database according to the query string provided in the request) in the page cached. Basically what I need is something like * which can be used in the NETWORK and FALLBACK sections.

If there is no such way to specify this in the manifest file, what is the best approach to solve this? For example, making the manifest itself dynamic and including the resources based on a query string passed to that might work, but it involves getting the list of resources from the db again.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I specify a wildcard in the HTML5 cache manifest to load all images in a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001196/how-do-i-specify-a-wildcard-in-the-html5-cache-manifest-to-load-all-images-in-a)

Comment: @robertc - Not quite. That question is about getting all the files in a directory on the server. What I want to do is to cache all the resources referenced in the html page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a wildcard in the CACHE section.

The approach you described seems practicable. But why retrieving the resources from DB again? once you've fetched them all, give them to a listener which does the generation, or store them in a session attribute where you can fetch them to generate the manifest.